# Magnetising a hollow steel ball from inside

Tags: magnetic-fields

Suppose a hollow iron/steel ball is magnetised from the inside by placing a magnet inside. Will the magnetic field on the outside of the steel ball be fairly uniform?
Does anyone know if there's any way to visualise the magnetic field in such a setting?

I'm asking because I'm trying to magnetise a hollow steel ball so that it can make contact with another steel ball. I want to see if the magnetised ball rotates, the other ball will also rotate but in a reverse direction.

Thanks